# how to terminate any application on End Call pressed in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, exit

I am starting an activity on`"TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK"` and it works well also. but in`"TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE"` i want to terminate that previously opened activity. I tried setting global variable, and that  global variable interact my activity, on that variable's true value i tried to `"finish()"` that activity. But as `"TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE"` done, i become helpless. Can you please help me out?

As so many application uses`END CALL` and `HOME BUTTON`, can we implement these by logically in real application?

I mentioned

```
1) TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK
2) TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE are in MyReceiver class which extends BroadcastReceiver.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having so much trouble with above question, i come to solve this by logically!!

you just have to add this code into your activity

```
 PhoneStateListener listener;

      // Get the telephony manager
      telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

      // Create a new PhoneStateListener
      listener = new PhoneStateListener() 
      {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

          switch (state) 
          {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                Log.i("MainScreen", "IDLE");                    
                finish(); // It will close current activity on pressing the END CALL Button!!
                break;

          }

        }
      };

      // Register the listener with the telephony manager
      telephonyManager.listen(listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

Comment: i m also doing same but my issue not resolved unable to finish activity on miss bell